# Card content doesn't adjust to screen size at breakpoint

Tags: html, css, flexbox, containers, media-queries

I'm trying to create a greeting card on the homepage of my website, but I run into a problem when I tried to make a breakpoint at 600px.

The card contains two parts, one with some text and one with an image.

When creating the breakpoint the problem that has occured was that the card did adjust to the screen size but the text and the image didn't.

Here is the  code:

```css
.box-container {
  margin: 10px ;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.03);
  
 }
.box1-side {
    flex: 0;
}
    
  
.box1-content,
.box1-side,
{
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
  color: darkslategray;
  overflow: hidden;
}


.box1-side {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.box1-content {
  background: whitesmoke;
  flex: 4;
  padding: 30px 40px;

}

.box1-side {
  background-image: url("https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/5a3a11268a02c7220dc5c3bf/1558972772276-5RJZIHJRIOESKPVVKLGF/ke17ZwdGBToddI8pDm48kO2pS9cMHbO4RvHPc8Skf1tZw-zPPgdn4jUwVcJE1ZvWhcwhEtWJXoshNdA9f1qD7SSwGn0TPzISNt3iSJufpcvR7xFZ2oYA-YTitnkXPCuTgiUfhLEJ_Uxi_cK3qclb8w/logo_economice.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  flex: 2;
}

@media(max-width:600px) {
    .box-container {
        margin: 1rem 0.7rem 1rem;
        max-width: 80vw
    }

}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="box-container">
  <div class="box1-content content ">
    <h1>Some text here</h1>
    <p class="text-lg">And some other text here</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box1-side">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I tried writing the box content and the side which contains the image inside the media query but didn't seem to work. Or maybe I missed something at this point considering that I'm a beginner.

How could I reduce the size of the text and the image as well?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure about your issue. What do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: I am trying to reduce the size of the text and the image as well.

Comment: Well, like this? https://jsfiddle.net/e8fj05t7/

Comment: That doesn't seem to work to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. for the image: use `background-size: contain;` propertyy to make the image fit the container
2. for the text: you have to reduce body font-size on 600px breakpoint.

   a good solution is to use `em` css unit on font size which is relative to body font-size [read more info about css units from here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)

demo:

```css
.box-container {
            margin: 10px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 300px;
            display: flex;
            align-items: stretch;
            box-shadow: 0 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);

        }

        .box1-side {
            flex: 0;
        }


        .box1-content,
        .box1-side {
            transition: all .3s ease-out;
            color: darkslategray;
            overflow: hidden;
        }


        .box1-side {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: flex-end;
        }

        .box1-content {
            background: whitesmoke;
            flex: 4;
            padding: 30px 40px;
        }
        .box1-content h1 { 
            font-size: 2em;
        }

        .box1-side {
            background-image: url("https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/5a3a11268a02c7220dc5c3bf/1558972772276-5RJZIHJRIOESKPVVKLGF/ke17ZwdGBToddI8pDm48kO2pS9cMHbO4RvHPc8Skf1tZw-zPPgdn4jUwVcJE1ZvWhcwhEtWJXoshNdA9f1qD7SSwGn0TPzISNt3iSJufpcvR7xFZ2oYA-YTitnkXPCuTgiUfhLEJ_Uxi_cK3qclb8w/logo_economice.png");
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center;
            background-size: contain;
            flex: 2;
        }

        @media(max-width:600px) {
            .box-container {
                margin: 1rem 0.7rem 1rem;
                max-width: 80vw
            }
            body { 
                font-size: 8px;
            }

        }
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="box-container">
    <div class="box1-content content ">
      <h1>Some text here</h1>
      <p class="text-lg">And some other text here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box1-side">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It adjusts the image, but for the text it didn't seem to work.

Comment: It's already working, I've edited answer and reduced font-size much more if you want to check

Comment: ThIs solved my problem almost entirely, I just need to replace the body inside the media query because it messes up my whole page. Thank you!

Comment: a bad solutions using only css: is to have to divs: display first div in large size and the other div in small sizes, the best solutions is to change content using js

Comment: check [this demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-mcclintock-njij6) for solution using only css